# ActionBar with Tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

Hello I am trying to put a `TabLayout` inside the `ActionBar`, not below it. Is it possible to be done?

I have searched around and found the `ActionBar.Tab` class, but it is already deprecated. Any other ideas please?

Comment: Yes, but I would still like to have the Back button to navigate back to previous `Activity` @DanielNugent

Comment: may be you try with adding TabLayout in toolbar and just set that toobar as your actionbar and set property to back button getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own Layout with back button and Tab Layout. You can use this layout at top  with no ActionBar. On Back click programmatically call `onBackPressed()` method.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great idea, but then the backButton wouldnt be the same as the system back button. Thanks for answering!

Comment: you can download back button icon from here. https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases. With selectableItemBackgroundBorderless as background and Material Icon you backButton will look like system back button.

Comment: I never forget :). One thing that bugs me is that the app will run on different versions of Android so the back button would be different on each versions.

Comment: If you use ToolBar then It will look like Material in all versions of Android

Comment: I am using the support ActionBar. Okay then thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I used the library below for tabs in example code. (Add the line to your app's gradle)

```
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
```

And than you can use a toolbar layout like below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.MyApp.Toolbar.Solid" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:background="@color/AppPrimary"
            app:pstsIndicatorColor="#fff"
            app:pstsIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:pstsTabTextAllCaps="false"
            app:pstsTabTextColor="@color/tabTextColor"
            app:pstsTabTextSize="16sp"
            app:pstsUnderlineColor="@color/AppPrimary"
            app:pstsUnderlineHeight="4dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are the styles i used in example layout:

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.Toolbar.Solid" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/AppPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <!-- Parent theme sets colorControlNormal to textColorPrimary. -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

In your activity's layout you have to include your toolbar like below:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_tabs" />
```

And you have to set your toolbar as support actionbar and to use it as an actonbar.

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar)findviewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Add a viewpager to your activity's layout: (Where you add your toolbar)

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        />
```

Create an adapter for your viewpager like below:

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<YourModel> mObjects;

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<YourModel> mObjects) {
        super(fm);
        this.mObjects = mObjects;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new YourPagerFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mObjects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mObjects.get(position).getName();
    }
}
```

Finally, find your viewpager, pager sliding tab strip, create a new pager adapter and set it to your viewpager like below:

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
PagerSlidingTabStrip mTabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
TabsAdapter mAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), objects);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mTabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Good luck.

Comment: There's really no need to use third party libraries for tabs anymore.  Best to use a TabLayout from the design library: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: You're right. But in my project i need some spesifications on tabs so i used this library. I put my project code.